# Physics in my game gives a wrong result with vsync turned off C++

Tags: c++, game-physics, physics

I calculate Newtonian physics based on gravitation in my 2D game. It works exactly how it's supposed to, when vsync is turned on (60fps), but once I turn it off and gain about 3.5k fps, the character starts to fall incredibly fast. The answer seems obvious, I just need to multiply character's velocity by deltaTime, but I already do that and still no result. It slows down the character a bit, but seems to be sort of not enough..

this is what character's update function looks like:

```cpp
void Update(float deltaTime) {
  if (!onGround) {
    acceleration += -Physics::g; // 9.81f
    /* EDIT: THIS IS WHAT IT ACTUALLY LOOKS LIKE, sorry*/
    SetPosition(position + Vec2(0.0f, 1.0f) * deltaTime * acceleration);
    /* instead of this:
    SetPosition(position + Vec2(0.0f, 1.0f) * acceleration); */
    if (ceiling) {
      acceleration = 0;
      ceiling = false;
    }
  } else {
    acceleration = 0;
  }
}
```

and here's the calculation of deltaTime

```cpp
inline static void BeginFrame() {
  currentTime = static_cast<float>(glfwGetTime()); // Time in seconds
  delta = (currentTime - lastTime);
  lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You multiplied the character's velocity, but didn't show the code?

Comment: deltaTime unused.

Comment: @MikeCAT Just edited the code in the question

Comment: @S.M. just corrected the code.

Comment: BTW, you have miswritten velocity as `acceleration`

Comment: If you do not consider elapsed time since last character movement (deltaTime) your pixel scaled movements will occur with every new frame. Try and keep it separated from game main loop. When you do not limit frame rate by 60 hits per second, your character moves approximately 60 times in a second (3.5k).

Comment: Position is determined by the formula p0 + a*(t - t0)^2 / 2. Your code does not program such formula.

Comment: The cast to `float` loses an awful lot of precision. With your needed precision being 1/3500 you could be getting close to the limits.  You will at least be getting rounding / precision errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The acceleration means how large the velocity increases *per unit time*, so you should multiply `deltaTime` to the acceleration, not only to the velocity.

In other words,

```
acceleration += -Physics::g; // 9.81f
```

should be:

```
acceleration += deltaTime * -Physics::g; // 9.81f
```

Comment: No. Acceleration should be constant on the surface of the Earth. I think the OP miswrote the *velocity*.

Comment: You are both right. OP's "acceleration" variable should be called "velocity" and should be computed as above.

Comment: @Eugen then there are three choices: 1) unbind physics from rendering passes 2) limit frame rate or 3) adapt phase parameters of moving objects to frame rate. But latter may get buggy results. It's very well known bug in Skyrim where on modern GPU  a horse flies into space after stepping up on a stone (and kills rider on landing). Too high frame rate outside of projected 40 fps resulted in huge acceleration and Skyrim without vsync could go 100+ frames. Fixed in VR\SE versions, afaik.

Comment: @EugenBondarev considering the numerical instability of floating point numbers it sounds to me like you want a discrete fixed physics time-step. Choose something like 100Hz and then just execute it enough times that you catch up to the frames time. You can even interpolate between the discrete physics step, if you need higher resolution, but only use the interpolations for display purposes, not for further physics calculations

Comment: After some more tests I realized that the character indeed started moving with the same velocity independently of whether vsync is turned on or off, when I use your suggestion, which was my initial goal. Although he started moving really slowly, multiplying the acceleration by some constant gives me the same satisfying result both with and without vsync, which is why I remove my comment, that denies the correctness of your answer and say thank you to all of you for helping me figure out the problems with my code.